# Trying to access an internal page from browser which doesn't have a url format ex: chrome://settings

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to analyze the html of chrome://settings and create a pop out window with toggled settings as a floating sidebar. I can't seem to link to chrome://settings because its not in URL format I have tried using **requests** , **selenium** , and **beautiful soup**.

How should I go about accessing the html documents from an internal page such as chrome://settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass ***chrome://settings*** as the *`url: str`* through `get()`as an argument as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('chrome://settings')
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: chrome_settings]