# How to open Wordpress server using Selenium, Python

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

My Wordpress website can be accessed by typing `localhost/wordpress` in the browser. So I thought if I pass that inside `driver.get()` in Selenium, I'll be able to access it. But it didn't turn out the way I wanted it to and got an error.

What should I try for this?

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 1):

Though manually when you pass *`localhost/wordpress`* in the url bar you are able to access the *My Wordpress website* but while passing through *`get()`* you have to pass the fully qualified *`url_string`*. Else you will face [`InvalidArgumentException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204715/7429447)

---

### Solution

You need to pass ***localhost/wordpress*** as the *`url: str`* through `get()`as an argument as follows:

```
driver.get("https://localhost/wordpress")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Trying to access an internal page from browser which doesn't have a url format ex: chrome://settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085698/trying-to-access-an-internal-page-from-browser-which-doesnt-have-a-url-format-e)